# Sum of Digits in Pl/SQL (Error In extracting Digits)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have Written Following Code :

```
DECLARE
    n integer;
    s integer;
    d integer;
BEGIN
    n:=&n;
    while n!=0 loop
        d:=mod(n,10);
        s:=s+d;
        n:=n/10;
    end loop;
     dbms_output.put_line('output :'||s);           
end;
/
```

Input Value : 1234

Output Value : 4321 **(Perfect What I want)**

**But When I Tried with following (I found incorrect output)**

Input value : 5678

Output : 88761

Expected Output : 8765

Comment: Your program simply adds each digits of the input number. How can the output be 4321 for input 1234?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided didn't work for me but the error is because it is rounding this operation:

```
n:=n/10;
```

If you change it to this it should work:

```
n:=floor(n/10);  OR n:=trunc(n/10);
```

However it's not working for me, I needed to add something to s:=s+d. Here's my code:

```
DECLARE
  n INTEGER;
  s INTEGER:= 0;
  d INTEGER;
  i INTEGER:= 0;
BEGIN
  n:= 5678;
  i:= length(to_char(n))-1; 
  WHILE n!=0 LOOP
    d:=mod(n,10);        
    s:=s+(d*power(10,i));
    i := i - 1;
    n:= trunc(n/10);        
  END LOOP;
  dbms_output.put_line('output :'||s);           
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `s` and a few more changes.

```
DECLARE
    n INTEGER;
    s integer := 0;
    d integer;
BEGIN
    n:=&n;
    while n!=0 loop
        d:=mod(n,10);
        s:=(s*10)+d;
        n:=floor(n/10);
    end loop;
     dbms_output.put_line('output :'||s);           
END;
/
```